# RETURN THE VARIABLE AS THE OUTPUT OF IF ELSE CONDITION IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle sql and trying to extract the value from table.
I want to extract certain column and a new value which should be the output of if else

Condition I am trying:

```
select name, variable 1 (this value should be the value returning from if else condition) from table1
```

what I tried till now

```
BEGIN
    IF columnA== 'xxx' OR PM == 1 THEN
        columnA:= 'xxx';
    ELSIF columnA== 'yyy' AND PM == 0 THEN
        columnA:= 'yyy';
    END IF;
END;
```

So the variable1 should be 'columnA' value which is returned from if else

How can I do this? if not guide me to right path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting your current if else logic to a `CASE` expression, we can try:

```sql
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN columnA = 'xxx' OR PM = 1 THEN 'xxx'
            WHEN columnA = 'yyy' AND PM = 0 THEN 'yyy' END AS variable1
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. interesting that comparison operator in SQL is '=' not '=='

Comment: I guess that is a function of what you learn first and use the most. I always think `==` is bizarre.